# Check if element exist JEST tests

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test if `sgn.init()` after call, generate and append element to DOM. However `document.querySelector('.class')` seems to always return null, even if I tried to add it manually in test function. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
test('shoud be rendered', () => {
    sgn.init();
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.classList.add('.element');
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    console.log(document.querySelector('.element'))

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given the div a class of `.element`.  Meaning that your class name contains a dot.

Try with `classList.add('element')`

The dot is only needed when searching, not creating.